# Unix diff ignoring lines ending with a sequence

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have two files

File 1

```
INFO  : temp0 Directory
            created
INFO  : temp0 Directory created
```

file2

```
INFO  : reuse temp1
```

So While differencing these two file i want to ignore statement that end with `Directory created` .
I write

```
diff -I 'Directory created' file1 file2
```

So this statement is ignoring second line from file1 successfully but it is not ignoring first line which contain `Directory created` in separate line.

So if anybody know solution please help me out!

Comment: Could you show us an example output you'd like to see? Just `reuse temp1` as an added line?

Comment: -I means ignore matching lines following a regular expression. You example has no matching lines.

Comment: @MichałGórny I want output like this `> INFO : reuse temp1` , I want to ignore both statement of file1 which contain **Directory created**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the simplest solution would be to filter out these lines from the first file. For example, you can do this using the following awk script:

```
# if line contains 'Directory created', just skip it.
/Directory created/ {
    had_dir = ""
    next
}

# if line contains sole 'Directory', store it and lookup next line.
/Directory/ {
    had_dir = $0
    next
}

# if line contains sole 'created' and we stored a line (which means
# it contained 'Directory'), then delete the stored one and skip
# (effectively, skip both).
/created/ && had_dir {
    had_dir = ""
    next
}

# otherwise, if we stored a line, print it.
had_dir {
    print had_dir
    had_dir = ""
}

# and print the current line.
{
    print
}
```

If your input is more complex, you may need to adjust the regexes a bit.

Then, use the script to filter out first file:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file1 | diff - file2
0a1
> INFO  : reuse temp1
```

Note that you're passing `-` as first argument to `diff`, to make it read the piped output of `awk` instead of the file.

And also note that the line offsets will no longer be correct.

Comment: How can i write `awk -f script.awk file1 | diff - file2` in tcl script . I tried this `set job [concat $awkExec -f "/home/user1/Desktop/script.awk" $goldDir | $diffExec -r -b - $outDir >& $result]
`  Where golddir and outdir are Directory name but above tcl script not working..

Comment: @JOhn: I have never ever used tcl, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly -I will match **only** in case if **all** lines in a **block of difference** will match. In the case you described - the condition does not hold.

```
diff -I "INFO" 1 2 | grep -v "Directory created"
```

might work for you, however it doesn't calculate diff block boundaries properly

hope that helps